# What is the immigration policy among different German parties?

Tags: parties, policy, immigration, germany

With the election coming next month, the immigration policy should be one of the primary issues on the election.

I know AfD strictly opposes to the immigration, while Merkel's CDU generally support the immigration. But how does the policy by SPD, Left, Green, CSU, and FDP differ from CDU? And how is it different among different types of immigrants including refugees?

Comment: You forgot the CSU, which due to its special role is quite important in this context.

Comment: @Roland Isn't it in a coalition with CDU? I thought they share more or less the same view.

Comment: They have a strong focus on representing their Bavarian voters, who are usually on the more conservative site. On average, the CSU is more conservative (and more populist) than the CDU.

Comment: @Roland Anyway I updated!

Answer (score 14):

Below are the immigration stances taken by some of the major parties in Germany.

### Social Democratic Party (SPD)

The Social Democratic Party is in favour of a points-based system, similar to that of Canada. Immigrants will be accessed based on various criteria, mentioned below.

> "The core of the law is a **point system modeled on the Canadian system**," Oppermann told the newspaper Bild am Sonntag. The law **would not change rules** on refugees and migrants applying for asylum in Germany, he said.
>
> Oppermann said the plan would **assess immigration applications** based on age, education, work experience, language skills and ability to integrate into German society, with a target of **allowing 25,000 immigrants to enter in the first year**.

<sup>Source: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-germany-migrants-spd-idUSKBN1310JW</sup>

### Alliance 90/The Greens (Green)

The Green Party proposes a "talent card" and their immigration policy is described as the most liberal. They believe that the country needs a law to control the influx of immigrants and provide migrants with legal certainty.

> "It is a card with which **highly-qualified workers and their families can move to Germany without already having a job**," said Katrin Göring-Eckardt, the Greens' parliamentary group leader. "They have a year to try to find a job in Germany." During this time, **no social services are provided; applicants must earn their living**.

<sup>Source: http://www.dw.com/en/germanys-green-party-outlines-talent-card-immigration-plan/a-38297650</sup>

### Bavarian Christian Social Union (CSU)

The Bavarian Christian Social Union wants major reforms to German immigration laws, advocating for an upper limit of 200,000 asylum seekers that the country should accept each year and want those who haven't been given a right to asylum to enter the country.

> It also includes rules which would affect migrants more generally, such as the abolition of dual citizenship and "the banning of the burqa in public to the greatest extent that is legally possible."
>
> ...
>
> “In the future, **priority must be given to migrants who come from our Christian western cultural area**,” the paper states. “Such a law would be a clear deterrent to illegal migration. A state should be able to decide for itself whom it accepts. Migrants shouldn’t be the ones making the decision.”

<sup>Source: https://www.thelocal.de/20160908/bavarian-csu-call-for-drastic-tightening-of-immigration-laws</sup>

### Die Linke (The Left)

Die Linke is in favour of making Europe more refugee-friendly

> They claim to promote the "unconditional right to stay and proper accommodation, social protection and equal rights for all refugees".
>
> ---
>
> Surprisingly united, on the other hand, are Germany's Left Party and industry representatives. Both are **in favor of immigrants**, but **reject a law to control them based on points**.

<sup>Sources: https://www.thelocal.de/20140514/what-do-die-linke-want-for-europe & http://www.dw.com/en/spd-presents-plans-for-immigration-law/a-18290888</sup>

### Free Democrats (FDP)

The Free Democrats wants Germany's borders to stay open, but control the inflows of migrants and manage the number with Germany's EU partners.

> Germany needed to give “a clear signal to migrants, that the possibilities of Germany and Europe are limited”, he says. “The false impression should not exist that anyone who comes to us automatically has the possibility of receiving work, housing and education and can stay for good.”

Their stance on immigration is "both tougher and softer" than the current rules.

> It would send Syrian refugees home once the civil war in their homeland ends and **establish a point system for immigrants** to lure only the most qualified, but it proposes a **shorter path to citizenship** and even the use of English as a second language in government offices to make life easier for newcomers.

<sup>Sources: https://www.ft.com/content/acee85e6-2b44-11e6-a18d-a96ab29e3c95 & https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-06-22/germany-s-free-democrats-are-back-in-action</sup>

*(all emphasis mine)*

Comment: Good answer. However, I don't think CSU's plan to ban burqa in public places should be considered as an immigration policy. It would apply to the whole population, homeborn or not, and about 99,9% of immigrants or would-be immigrants are not concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! But how certain are you that this is still true in August 2017? Some of the links seem to be a bit outdated; I meant the policy of each party at the 2017 election.

Comment: @Blaszard You're welcome! I can't be exactly sure, but the positions of the parties shouldn't differ much since they're all from after the 2013 German federal election and they're the most updated sources that I could find.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly , The Greens party is very compatible and suitable for the German economy. However , they bring negative outcomes for the public. They would seek to remove restrictions on visas for LOW-SKILLED WORKERS and lift the ban on multiple immigration issues. (This is because they are a party that has eyes for the economy and business) Jobs that could have been given to the local unemployed Germans , are instead given to poor and unqualified immigrants from countries such as Vietnam and Indonesia.

You can ask how would those immigrants get into Germany so easily. Simple , The Greens already answered it. They said that they do not have to learn German to enter the country. That is already a huge barrier lifted from the path of immigration for these LOW-SKILLED foreign immigrants.

Not hating on them or a nationalist. But just saying , you can be open on immigration. But there must always be a limit and some barriers.

Comment: One reference to confirm Greens policy would be great ("They would seek to remove restrictions on visas for LOW-SKILLED WORKERS and lift the ban on multiple immigration issues. "). Also, I would remove personal opinions such as "The Greens party is very compatible and suitable for the German economy" and "Not hating on them or a nationalist. But just saying (..)", as most SE sites are into facts more than personal opinions.